# Count grid cells overlapping with target polygon

Tags: arcgis-pro, overlapping-features, count

I am working with ArcGIS Pro trying to obtain the number of grid cells of a polygon grid (purple) overlapping with different target polygons (green), e.g. 9 grid cells for the uppermost polygon.

[image]

The 'Count overlapping Features' tool splits the target polygons according to the grid lines, which is not what I am looking for. Is there another tool or work around to accomplish this?

Comment: Select by location followed by Get Count.   https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/navigation/select-features-by-location.htm    https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of these tools! However, do you know how I can get the selected cells counted by target polygon? I am just getting an overall count

Comment: You could use an iterator within Model Builder to select each polygon at a time, then return the intersection count for that selection.  If you are unfamiliar with iterators in Model Builder you should post those concerns as a new questions because running conversation in comments are frowned upon at GIS SE.  A spacial join will also populate the green polygons with an intersection count so that is also an option for you.

Comment: Great, I will try this. Thank you very much. Do you want to post your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Tabulate area does that